# TADOQuery: 'EDatabaseError type mismatch for field 'MyField', expecting: String actual: FixedWideChar'

Tags: delphi, delphi-2007, type-mismatch, tadoquery

I have 3 different databases (development, homolog and prod), each of them in one of the following Oracle versions: 11g and 10g.

I'm using a TADOQuery to query for some data in only one of those databases at a time.

When I run my app in dev or prod it returns the data perfectly.
But when I run it in homolog i get the following error message:

'EDatabaseError type mismatch for field 'MyField', expecting: String actual: FixedWideChar'

I already checked and the DDL is the same for the 3 databases, so it's not a problem of data type. 
Also, MyField is a CHAR(1) in all of them.

Can anybody help me?

Comment: With no code and no DDL, there's not much we can do to help you here. You've mentioned three servers and two Oracle versions. Which versions of Oracle are working and which one is not? Obviously, there's some difference between them. What Oracle client is in use in your ADOQuery? What type is the field? What is the `TField` class (type) in your code?

Comment: Please post your solution as an answer, if it solves the problem. Answering your own question is allowed here (it's explained in the [faq]), and posting as an answer makes it useful to others in the future. If you don't want to do that, you can always delete your question. The wrong thing to do is to edit and say "Solved.". :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solved the problem!
The answer came from this post: http://objectmix.com/ado-dao-rdo-rds/392318-fixedwidechar-adodb-problem.html

I had to fix a bug in the ADODB.pas changing the following line

```
compatible:= FieldDef.DataType in [ftstring,ftwidestring]
```

into

```
compatible:= FieldDef.DataType in [ftstring,ftwidestring,ftfixedWideChar]
```