# android desktop sqlite error datasnap "unsupported type"

Tags: android, sqlite, delphi

i have a problem with my project.
i have a plan to build restaurant cross platform program (android-desktop) using IDE Delphi XE.
i'm not expert on programming either, so i need help from everyone...

so, i tried to make 1 input form for desktop client, then 1 input form for android client, and connect them to SQLite on server using datasnap.

When i tried to input record to SQLite from desktop client with clientdataset, the result is error "field 'kode_level' is of an unsupported type".
but if i try to insert from my android client, the result is success.

and then i try to use sql server for database, it success on desktop client, but failed on android client (maybe because ODBC thing)..

so, if anyone have solution... i will gladly hear it... thankyou everyone..

Comment: may be this “unsupported type” because of the DB data not match with the column type

Comment: thanks for quick reply. i tried to change blobtype from field of clientdataset to 'ftWideString' but when i run it stop working...

Comment: what is the error now

Comment: it pop up another window "Stopped Working", and then when i click "close the program", it pop up another window "Application Error" and written below is "Exception EDatabaseError in module ClientPC.exe at 00350E02. ClientDataSet1: Type mismatch for field 'kode_level', expecting: WideString actal: WideMemo.

Comment: Type mismatch for field 'kode_level', expecting: WideString actal: WideMemo. – check this

Comment: that's what i'm so confused about... i tried to change it back to 'ftWideMemo' but the first error come again, i mean that 'unsupported type'

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16678695

Comment: i mean the error want me to change it to ftwidememo, but when i change it, it said unsupported type.....

Comment: thanks a lot.. i will try, please wait

Comment: i understand what it said, but i didn't use ADO, i'm using SQLConnection, SQLTable and other... >_< i'm sorry... or should i try use ADO?

Comment: you can use, but why you are getting error in SQLConnection ? i am thinking about that

Comment: one for sure, it's connected to data type... please contact me if you find something, thanks a lot...